# uncaught security exception for the webkitNotifications.createNotification used in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was trying out to display a simple desktop notification thru chrome extensions. But I keep this error message:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
```

This is my manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["myurl/*"],
       "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "chrome-logo.png"
  ]
}
```

the content script is :

```
 var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
  'chrome-logo.png',  // icon url - can be relative
  'Hello!',  // notification title
  'Lorem ipsum...'  // notification body text
);
notification.show();
```

I added this line in the manifest.json file, but that didn't help either:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' ",
```

what is the work around for this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the [webkitNotifications](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/) api, which requires that the user gives previous consent to display notifications.

From an extension you can use the [chrome.notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html) api instead, but you need to do it from the background page, not from a content script. If you need to display a notification based on something that happens on a webpage, you can send a message from a content script to your background page telling it to display the notification.

Comment: Any specific reason that I have to associate backgroundPage.. Is there no way I can do it from the content script?

Comment: @theGreatDanton it's just how Chrome extensions work. Most chrome.* apis are only available from the background page.